# Data is not sharding in Postgres 10 when used postgres_fdw extension

Tags: postgresql

Using postgres_fdw extension in Postgres 10, I am trying to shard my data.

As per below URL, I performed steps.
http://www.3manuek.com/postgresmanualsharding

Initially, I created 3 databases in my server, test1,test2 and test3. Then I did the following.

1. Created extension postgres_fdw.
2. Created 3 servers like below.

   ```
   CREATE SERVER shard1_main FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw 
     OPTIONS(host 'localhost',port '5432',dbname 'test1');
   ```
3. Mapped users for all 3 shards like below.

   ```
   CREATE USER MAPPING FOR rdarukumalli SERVER shard1_main OPTIONS(user 'rdarukumalli');
   ```
4. Created main table and foreign tables.
       CREATE TABLE main (shardKey char(2), key bigint, avalue text);

   ```
   CREATE SERVER shard1_main FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw 
     OPTIONS(host ‘localhost',port '5432',dbname 'test1');

   CREATE SERVER shard2_main FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw 
     OPTIONS(host ‘localhost',port '5432',dbname 'test2');

   CREATE SERVER shard3_main FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw 
     OPTIONS(host ‘localhost',port '5432',dbname 'test3');
   ```
5. Insert data into main table.

   ```
   INSERT INTO main
   SELECT '0' || round(random()*1+1),i.i,random()::text
   FROM generate_series(1,20000) i(i) ;
   ```

After inserting data, when I verify the shards, I don't see the data is inserted into those shards. Only in main table, data lies.

But the explain command is correctly showing shards based on shard key.

Is there anything I am missing??

Comment: Paste `ddl` code of point 4.

Comment: and the inserts of 5.

Comment: updated my question with queries I used for 4 and 5.

Comment: You need to create trigger for foreign partitions. To quote manual: `Partitions can also be foreign tables (see CREATE FOREIGN TABLE), although these have some limitations that normal tables do not. For example, data inserted into the partitioned table is not routed to foreign table partitions.`

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński: is that still true for declarative partitioning introduced in v10?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, I have taken that quote from current declarative partitioning heading: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE

Comment: Thank you @ŁukaszKamiński   It worked.

Comment: I can see using the trigger made it slow. Is there any alternative of this??